# Highlight column when a row is clicked, depending on condition

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

We have a large matrix with lists of servers on the rows and persons as columns. Then we mark the column/row with an X if the person has access to the server. Pretty basic. But as the matrix grows, it becomes more difficult to quickly find the right person with access. 
So I'd like some way to make it easier to use

[image]
In the example above I have clicked on the row "Resource B" and would like all the columns where there is an "X" (User 1, User 2) to be highlighted somehow. Then if I click the row for "Resource C", "User 1" should be highlighted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    lastCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    For Each cell In Range(Cells(Target.Row, 1), Cells(Target.Row, lastCol))
        If cell = "x" Then
            cell.EntireColumn.Interior.Color = 65535
        Else
            cell.EntireColumn.Interior.Color = xlNone
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

**Important:** Insert the macro in the desired Worksheet object, not in a module object.
Or else `Worksheet_SelectionChange` won't work.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Seems like this is what you need:

[link](http://chandoo.org/wp/2012/07/11/highlight-row-column-of-selected-cell-using-vba/)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.